# asp.net print the results of a sql command

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following sql command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE  ID = 'john' ", con);
```

How can i output the results of the following command in C# to my webpage?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the introductory: "How to get data on a web page?" answer, then maybe this is a little more helpful:

1. Add a new page MyPage.aspx to your
   web application
2. Add a GridView to that page
3. On Page_Load do the code
   below

{

```
string strSQLconnection = 
"Data Source=dbServer;Initial Catalog=yourDatabase;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = 
    new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE  ID = 'john' ", con);     
con.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to execute the SQL command, then iterate through the data. Assuming this query returns one row, your code might look like:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    if (!reader.HasRows) {
        // User not found
    }
    else {
        reader.Read();      // Advance to first row

        // Sample data access
        var name = reader["name"];
        var otherColumnValue = reader["otherColumnName"];
    }
}
```